# Get Environment Variables of Child Process in VC++

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Okay, here's essentially what I am trying to do. I have a process `P1`. This process needs to invoke the Visual Studio command-line compiler `cl.exe` in a separate process `P2` (obviously). However, as everyone who has ever used the Visual Studio command-line compiler knows, you cannot simply invoke `cl.exe` and expect a good experience. You instead have to first run the batch script `%VSXXXCOMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat` (where `XXX` is the Visual Studio version number). This script sets a few key environment variables used by the compiler (such as what to use as the include path). Using a batch script, this is insanely easy to do:

```
call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
...
cl Foo.cpp Bar.cpp ...
```

since just calling a batch file from a batch script runs in the same process (and thus the added environment variables are persistent). This is what I used to do before I realized that I need more flexibility and decided to port my script to C++ which, so far, has worked wonderfully. That is, until I got to the point where I need to implement the actual compilation.

So, that's the problem I am ultimately trying to solve. The best idea I have come up with is to invoke `cmd.exe /c "%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"` in a separate process `P3` using `CreateProcess`, wait for that process to terminate, and then extract the modified environment variables from that child process. That is, `P1` creates `P3` and waits for it to finish. `P1` then sets `P3`'s environment variables as its own. `P1` then creates `P2` with these environment variables set. So the code looks *roughly* as follows (minus all error checking):

```
...
CreateProcess(TEXT("cmd"), TEXT("/c \"%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat\""), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

/* Set current process environment using pi.hProcess */
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

...

CreateProcess(TEXT("cl"), TEXT("..."), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

That would be the preferred solution. I am not entirely sure if such a thing is possible, but based off my research, it appears there is a way to do this in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0.aspx), and [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) appears to be able to read the environment of arbitrary processes, so I would assume such a solution is possible. I just can't seem to find any documented functions that are able to get environment variables from child processes. There's also an *old* discussion that is similar to this on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc9896a4-4e3a-407d-a922-5fa725326160/invoking-clexe-using-createprocess?forum=vclanguage). One of the responses mentions setting `Merge Environment` to `yes`. Anyone know what that is/means? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

If it turns out this is not possible, alternate solutions I have thought about is (1) writing a batch script that simply calls `vsvars32.bat` and then invokes `cl.exe` with the input arguments, (2) invoking `cmd` instead of `cl` with arguments to run `vsvars32.bat` and then compile (similar to `1`, but more extensible... but not sure if possible), or (3) print the environment variables to a file and then read those in. I'd prefer not to use any of such solutions if possible.

I'm also open to alternate suggestions. Just know that 99% of what I need to do is already done, so clean, non-hacky solutions are preferred.

Comment: I'd invoke `cmd.exe` with `/c` and then `call vsvars32.bat && cl ....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clean way to do this is to run `vcvars32` to set all the environment variables and then run your process `P1`.

```
cmd /C vcvars32.bat && P1
```

Note that the user doesn't have to do this manually.  Create a shortcut with this target:

```
cmd /C ""C:\Some Path\vcvarsall.bat" && start /separate C:\SomeOtherPath\YourGui.exe"
```

This sets the environment variables and then launches your GUI app.  The `start /separate` stops the command-prompt lingering once the GUI app has started.  If you also want this to be convenient to run from the command-line you can put it all in a batch file.

If for some reason you don't want to do this, the simplest way to get the environment variables from a batch script is to run:

```
cmd /U /C vcvars32.bat && set
```

This writes the values to standard output in Unicode.  You can use a pipe to retrieve the values.  This is much less hacky than trying to retrieve the variables from the memory of another process.

N.B. If you want to test this at a command-prompt you need to run:

```
cmd /U /C "vcvars32.bat && set"
```

The quotes ensure that the `set` runs in the child command processor.

Comment: +1 for piping the output so it can be captured. The original process can call `CreateProcess()` to run `cmd.exe` with redirected output (there are examples on MSDN), and then include the captured values in the `lpEnvironment` parameter when calling `CreateProcess()` to run `cl.exe`.

Comment: The "clean" way is how I have been testing so far. The downside (apart from the user having to remember to run the script - VS120COMNTOOLS\vsvars32.bat is a long name!) is that it requires the process to have originated from the command line. I plan to add a graphical client for configuring options and what-not later, so having to invoke that from the command line **after** running vsvars would be slightly inconvenient. Piping the output is something I was trying to avoid if I could, but it appears to be the most viable solution at this point.

Comment: @Duncan: Although the command-processor is involved, your app doesn't have to be launched by the user from the command-line.  I've updated my answer to explain how to handle this.

Comment: Eeeh, that's still not preferable for a number of reasons, debugging being a big one.

Answer (score 1):

Do not retrieve and set environment variables across process boundaries.  Run `vsvars32.bat` and `cl.exe` in the same process, like they are meant to be.  `cmd.exe` lets you execute multiple commands at one time using its `&&` operator:

```
cmd.exe /c "\"%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat\" && cl ..."
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to? I need to potentially compile hundreds of executables and I'd rather avoid taking the time to run `vsvars` before each one