# Maintaining variables when executing cmd from C# application

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I want to call some cmd prompt commands from a .net C# application. However before the command is run I need to set up a varaibles within a batch file. Is there a way to maintain the variables to subsequent calls to the command prompt?

I provide an example below of the problem.

Say I have a simple batch file **C:\setEnv.bat** containing

```
set notepad=C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

Then if I have C# code like thus:

```
var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
string cmd1 = @"CALL C:\setEnv.bat";
string cmd2 = @"ECHO notepad=%notepad%>C:\test.txt";
proc1.UseShellExecute = true;

var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " +cmd1;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + cmd2;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Now I'm guessing that the **/C** is terminating the command prompt thus losing my variables but if I don't have it then the cmd prompt doesn't return after finishing the command.

I thought I could double the cmd1 & cmd2 to a single call but then I would need to do that for every call to the cmd prompt and feels a little redundant calling **C:\setenv.bat** again and again.

Comment: This is entirely by design.  A process normally inherits the environment of the program that starts it, any changes it makes to its environment are lost when the program terminates.  So get ahead by changing *your* environment or by using the ProcsesStartInfo.EnvirontmentVariables property.

Comment: I have a third party application that requires a good number of environment variables to be set up prior to running. I'm not sure which variable it needs and I'm looking to avoid to avoid "CALL setenv.bat && thirdPartyApp.exe" as the constant calling to setenv feels redundant. Will look into EnvironmentVariables property.

Answer (score 1):

You may use way in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222223/get-environment-variables-of-child-process-in-vc)

For example, use command "set" in cmd1:

```
string cmd1 = "\" CALL C:\\setEnv.bat && set \"";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//...
process.Start();
string variables = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// next parse variables string
```

And before start second process set parsed variables in "startInfo.EnvironmentVariables"

Answer (score 0):

A few issues/ideas:

1) How many values to you need to track from one execution to the next?  Primarily, can you just use the errorlevel return value or do you need more details?

2) Can you pipe the results of the first directly into the second as one call?

3) Can you output the values from the first call to a file and in the 2nd call, pipe that as input into the 2nd cmd?

4) I assume that you have some processing that is done after the first cmd is run, but before the 2nd cmd is called.  Could you create an .exe that can be called by the 1st batch file (after the other code) that does that processing.  That way, you have 3 cmds all of which can be run in the same environment and your variables stick around.